# SQL - Retrieve all records that appear within X seconds either side of a specified records datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, parameters

When I store a record in my SQL table it is stored with an eventDateTime.

I want to return all records where their eventDateTime is X seconds either side of a specified records eventDateTime.

I have tried it but it just won't work for me, I am getting nowhere.

Example:

Give me all the records that have an eventDateTime in the 10 seconds before and after a supplied record eventDateTime.

Can this be done? All help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using date logic.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.id = @id and
        t.datetime between dateadd(second, - @n, t2.datetime) and dateadd(second, @n, t2.datetime);
```

In this formulation, `@id` is the logic that represents the row you want to match, and `@n` is the number of seconds on either side.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: can you provide an example of what i can do in place of `@id`? In my case the row i want to match has a .status of "active" so i tried t2.status = 'active' but the results include some duplicate records which makes me think i dont understand how this works.

Comment: @learnsomemore . . . Perhaps you should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.